# How to store business ID in elasticsearch?

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to store tweets in some Elasticsearch index using Spring Data Elasticsearch (for tweet requesting , I'm using twitter4j).

I have followed some basic example and I'm using this basic annotated POJO (metadatas with complex type have been removed) :

```
@Document(indexName = "twitter", type = "tweet")
public class StorableTweet {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private String createdAt;
  private String text;
  private String source;
  private boolean isTruncated;
  private long inReplyToStatusId;
  private long inReplyToUserId;
  private boolean isFavorited;
  private boolean isRetweeted;
  private int favoriteCount;
  private String inReplyToScreenName;
  private String userScreenName = null;  

  // Getters/setters removed

}
```

To store a tweet using this model, I use :

```
public interface TweetRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<StorableTweet, Long> { 
}
```

and in my storing service :

```
tweetRepository.save(storableTweet);
```

It works fine, but my tweet Id is stored in "_id" (why not) and some other number coming from nowhere is stored in "id" (why....?) :

```
{
   "_index": "twitter",
   "_type": "tweet",
   **"_id": "655008947099840512"**, <-- this is the real tweet id
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source":
   {
       **"id": 655008947099840500**, <-- this number comes from nowhere
       "createdAt": "Fri Oct 16 15:14:37 CEST 2015",
       "text": "tweet text(...)",
       "source": "Twitter for iPhone",
       "inReplyToStatusId": -1,
       "inReplyToUserId": -1,
       "favoriteCount": 0,
       "inReplyToScreenName": null,
       "user": "971jml",
       "favorited": false,
       "retweeted": false,
       "truncated": false
   }
}
```

What I would like is either my tweet id stored in "_id" (and no "id" field), either my tweet id stored in "id" an having a generated number in "_id", and get rid of this random useless number in "id".

EDIT

mapping :

```
{
   "twitter":
   {
       "mappings":
       {
           "tweet":
           {
               "properties":
               {
                   "createdAt":
                   {
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "favoriteCount":
                   {
                       "type": "long"
                   },
                   "favorited":
                   {
                       "type": "boolean"
                   },
                   "inReplyToScreenName":
                   {
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "inReplyToStatusId":
                   {
                       "type": "long"
                   },
                   "inReplyToUserId":
                   {
                       "type": "long"
                   },
                   "retweeted":
                   {
                       "type": "boolean"
                   },
                   "source":
                   {
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "text":
                   {
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "truncated":
                   {
                       "type": "boolean"
                   },
                   "tweetId":
                   {
                       "type": "long"
                   },
                   "user":
                   {
                       "type": "string"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

EDIT 2 : It looks like the problem is not about @Id annotation but about "long" type. Some other longs (not all) are transformed (a few units more or less) when stored into elasticsearch via Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you update your question with the effective `tweet` mapping type `curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping/tweet`?

Comment: Sure (note : I've just renamed "id" in "tweetId" but it's the same result).